# Show value along with where needle is pointing in d3 gauge chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to show two values in my webpage for which i have made two gauges using d3. now both gauges point to different value but i am unable to show value along with the needle as using d3 functions is tricky for me. this is code which gives me two gauges

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <title>Gauge</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    body {
        font-family:  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 32px;
    }

    #power-gauge g.arc {
        fill: red;
    }

    #power-gauge g.pointer {
        fill: yellow;
        stroke: yellow;
    }
    
    #power-gauge g.label text {
        text-anchor: middle;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        fill: #000;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div> <h1> Sector Prosperity </h1>
</div>

<div id="action"></div>
<div id="action1"></div>
    
<script>
var gauge = function(container, configuration) {
    var that = {};
    var config = {
        size                        : 400,
        clipWidth                   : 400,
        clipHeight                  : 270,
        ringInset                   : 20,
        ringWidth                   : 90,
        
        pointerWidth                : 5,
        pointerTailLength           : 0,
        pointerHeadLengthPercent    : 0.85,
        
        minValue                    : 0,
        maxValue                    : 650,
        
        minAngle                    : -90,
        maxAngle                    : 90,
        
        transitionMs                : 750,
        
        majorTicks                  : 600,
        
        labelFormat                 : d3.format(',g'),
        labelInset                  : 100,
        
        arcColorFn                  : d3.interpolateHsl(d3.rgb('#f64e60'), d3.rgb('#41a4fe'))
    };
    var range = undefined;
    var r = undefined;
    var pointerHeadLength = undefined;
    var value = 0;
    
    var svg = undefined;
    var arc = undefined;
    var scale = undefined;
    var ticks = undefined;
    var tickData = undefined;
    var pointer = undefined;

    var donut = d3.layout.pie();
    
    function deg2rad(deg) {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }
    
    function newAngle(d) {
        var ratio = scale(d);
        var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
        return newAngle;
    }
    
    function configure(configuration) {
        var prop = undefined;
        for ( prop in configuration ) {
            config[prop] = configuration[prop];
        }
        
        range = config.maxAngle - config.minAngle;
        r = config.size / 2;
        pointerHeadLength = Math.round(r * config.pointerHeadLengthPercent);

        // a linear scale that maps domain values to a percent from 0..1
        scale = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([0,1])
            .domain([config.minValue, config.maxValue]);
            
        ticks = scale.ticks(config.majorTicks);
        tickData = d3.range(config.majorTicks).map(function() {return 1/config.majorTicks;});
        
        arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(r - config.ringWidth - config.ringInset)
            .outerRadius(r - config.ringInset)
            .startAngle(function(d, i) {
                var ratio = d * i;
                return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
            })
            .endAngle(function(d, i) {
                var ratio = d * (i+1);
                return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
            });
    }
    that.configure = configure;
    
    function centerTranslation() {
        return 'translate('+r +','+ r +')';
    }
    
    function isRendered() {
        return (svg !== undefined);
    }
    that.isRendered = isRendered;
    
    function render(newValue) {
        svg = d3.select(container)
            .append('svg:svg')
                .attr('class', 'gauge')
                .attr('width', config.clipWidth)
                .attr('height', config.clipHeight);
        
        var centerTx = centerTranslation();
        
        var arcs = svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'arc')
                .attr('transform', centerTx); 
                
                
        arcs.selectAll('path')
                .data(tickData)
            .enter().append('path')
                .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                    return config.arcColorFn(d * i);
                })
                .attr('d', arc);
        
        var lg = svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'label')
                .attr('transform', centerTx);
        lg.selectAll('text')
                .data(ticks)
            //.enter().append('text')
                .attr('transform', function(d) {
                    var ratio = scale(d);
                    var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio *                                                          range);
                    return 'rotate(' +newAngle +') translate(0,' +(config.labelInset - r) +')';
                })
                .text(config.labelFormat);

        var lineData = [ [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0], 
                        [0, -pointerHeadLength],
                        [-(config.pointerWidth / 2), 0],
                        [0, config.pointerTailLength],
                        [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0] ];
        var pointerLine = d3.svg.line().interpolate('monotone');
        var pg = svg.append('g').data([lineData])
                .attr('class', 'pointer')
                .attr('transform', centerTx);
                
        pointer = pg.append('path')
            .attr('d', pointerLine/*function(d) { return pointerLine(d) +'Z';}*/ )
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +config.minAngle + ')');
            
        update(newValue = 430);
        
        //== undefined ? 0 : newValue);
    }
    that.render = render;
    
    function update(newValue, newConfiguration) {
        if ( newConfiguration  !== undefined) {
            configure(newConfiguration);
        }
        var ratio = scale(newValue);
        var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
        pointer.transition()
            .duration(config.transitionMs)
            .ease('elastic')
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +newAngle +')');
    }
    that.update = update;

    configure(configuration);
    
    return that;
};
</script>

<script>
function onDocumentReady() {
    var powerGauge = gauge('#action', {
        size: 400,
        clipWidth: 400,
        clipHeight: 400,
        ringWidth: 80,
        maxValue: 650,
        transitionMs: 4000,
    });
    powerGauge.render();
    powerGauge.update(110);


    
    var powerGauge2 = gauge('#action1', {
        size: 400,
        clipWidth: 400,
        clipHeight: 400,
        ringWidth: 80,
        maxValue: 650,
        transitionMs: 4000,
    });
    powerGauge2.render();
    powerGauge2.update(500);
    

//window.setTimeout(function() {
//  custom.update(120);
//}, 4000);



window.setTimeout(function() {
  custom2.update(68);
}, 4000);
    
    
    // every few seconds update reading values
    //updateReadings();
    //setInterval(function() {
        //updateReadings();
    //}, 1000);
}

if ( !window.isLoaded ) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        onDocumentReady();
    }, false);
} else {
    onDocumentReady();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is how i want them to show. Can somebody provide me with a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a `<text>` element with `text-anchor='middle'`. You can also specify `alignment-baseline` attribute to adjust the text vertically:

```
valueText = pg.append('text').attr('text-anchor', 'middle');
```

2. Update its position (195 is radius, replace it with your constant):

```
 const a = newAngle / 180 * Math.PI + (newAngle < 0 ? Math.PI * 2 : 0);
 const x = 195 * Math.sin(a);
 const y = 195 * -Math.cos(a);
 valueText.text(newValue).attr('x', x).attr('y', y);
```

See it's working in the snippet:

```js
var gauge = function(container, configuration) {
    var that = {};
    var config = {
        size                        : 400,
        clipWidth                   : 400,
        clipHeight                  : 270,
        ringInset                   : 20,
        ringWidth                   : 90,
        
        pointerWidth                : 5,
        pointerTailLength           : 0,
        pointerHeadLengthPercent    : 0.85,
        
        minValue                    : 0,
        maxValue                    : 650,
        
        minAngle                    : -90,
        maxAngle                    : 90,
        
        transitionMs                : 750,
        
        majorTicks                  : 600,
        
        labelFormat                 : d3.format(',g'),
        labelInset                  : 100,
        
        arcColorFn                  : d3.interpolateHsl(d3.rgb('#f64e60'), d3.rgb('#41a4fe'))
    };
    var range = undefined;
    var r = undefined;
    var pointerHeadLength = undefined;
    var value = 0;
    
    var svg = undefined;
    var arc = undefined;
    var scale = undefined;
    var ticks = undefined;
    var tickData = undefined;
    var pointer = undefined;
    var valueText = undefined;

    var donut = d3.layout.pie();
    
    function deg2rad(deg) {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }
    
    function newAngle(d) {
        var ratio = scale(d);
        var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
        return newAngle;
    }
    
    function configure(configuration) {
        var prop = undefined;
        for ( prop in configuration ) {
            config[prop] = configuration[prop];
        }
        
        range = config.maxAngle - config.minAngle;
        r = config.size / 2;
        pointerHeadLength = Math.round(r * config.pointerHeadLengthPercent);

        // a linear scale that maps domain values to a percent from 0..1
        scale = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([0,1])
            .domain([config.minValue, config.maxValue]);
            
        ticks = scale.ticks(config.majorTicks);
        tickData = d3.range(config.majorTicks).map(function() {return 1/config.majorTicks;});
        
        arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(r - config.ringWidth - config.ringInset)
            .outerRadius(r - config.ringInset)
            .startAngle(function(d, i) {
                var ratio = d * i;
                return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
            })
            .endAngle(function(d, i) {
                var ratio = d * (i+1);
                return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
            });
    }
    that.configure = configure;
    
    function centerTranslation() {
        return 'translate('+r +','+ r +')';
    }
    
    function isRendered() {
        return (svg !== undefined);
    }
    that.isRendered = isRendered;
    
    function render(newValue) {
        svg = d3.select(container)
            .append('svg:svg')
                .attr('class', 'gauge')
                .attr('width', config.clipWidth)
                .attr('height', config.clipHeight);
        
        var centerTx = centerTranslation();
        
        var arcs = svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'arc')
                .attr('transform', centerTx); 
                
                
        arcs.selectAll('path')
                .data(tickData)
            .enter().append('path')
                .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                    return config.arcColorFn(d * i);
                })
                .attr('d', arc);
        
        var lg = svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'label')
                .attr('transform', centerTx);
        lg.selectAll('text')
                .data(ticks)
            //.enter().append('text')
                .attr('transform', function(d) {
                    var ratio = scale(d);
                    var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio *                                                          range);
                    return 'rotate(' +newAngle +') translate(0,' +(config.labelInset - r) +')';
                })
                .text(config.labelFormat);

        var lineData = [ [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0], 
                        [0, -pointerHeadLength],
                        [-(config.pointerWidth / 2), 0],
                        [0, config.pointerTailLength],
                        [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0] ];
        var pointerLine = d3.svg.line().interpolate('monotone');
        var pg = svg.append('g').data([lineData])
                .attr('class', 'pointer')
                .attr('transform', centerTx);
                
        pointer = pg.append('path')
            .attr('d', pointerLine)
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +config.minAngle + ')');

        valueText = pg.append('text').attr('text-anchor', 'middle');
        update(newValue = 430);
        
        //== undefined ? 0 : newValue);
    }
    that.render = render;
    
    function update(newValue, newConfiguration) {
        if ( newConfiguration  !== undefined) {
            configure(newConfiguration);
        }
        var ratio = scale(newValue);
        var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
        pointer.transition()
            .duration(config.transitionMs)
            .ease('elastic')
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +newAngle +')');
       
       let a = newAngle / 180 * Math.PI;
       if (a < 0) a += Math.PI * 2;
       const x = 195 * Math.sin(a);
       const y = 195 * -Math.cos(a);
       valueText.text(newValue).attr('x', x).attr('y', y);
    }
    that.update = update;

    configure(configuration);
    
    return that;
};
</script>

<script>
function onDocumentReady() {
    var powerGauge = gauge('#action', {
        size: 400,
        clipWidth: 400,
        clipHeight: 400,
        ringWidth: 80,
        maxValue: 650,
        transitionMs: 4000,
    });
    powerGauge.render();
    powerGauge.update(110);


    
    var powerGauge2 = gauge('#action1', {
        size: 400,
        clipWidth: 400,
        clipHeight: 400,
        ringWidth: 80,
        maxValue: 650,
        transitionMs: 4000,
    });
    powerGauge2.render();
    powerGauge2.update(500);
    

//window.setTimeout(function() {
//  custom.update(120);
//}, 4000);



window.setTimeout(function() {
  custom2.update(68);
}, 4000);
    
    
    // every few seconds update reading values
    //updateReadings();
    //setInterval(function() {
        //updateReadings();
    //}, 1000);
}

if ( !window.isLoaded ) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        onDocumentReady();
    }, false);
} else {
    onDocumentReady();
}
</script>
</body>
</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <title>Gauge</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    body {
        font-family:  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 32px;
    }

    #power-gauge g.arc {
        fill: red;
    }

    #power-gauge g.pointer {
        fill: yellow;
        stroke: yellow;
    }
    
    #power-gauge g.label text {
        text-anchor: middle;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        fill: #000;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div> <h1> Sector Prosperity </h1>
</div>

<div id="action"></div>
<div id="action1"></div>
    
<script>
var gauge = function(container, configuration) {
    var that = {};
    var config = {
        size                        : 400,
        clipWidth                   : 400,
        clipHeight                  : 270,
        ringInset                   : 20,
        ringWidth                   : 90,
        
        pointerWidth                : 5,
        pointerTailLength           : 0,
        pointerHeadLengthPercent    : 0.85,
        
        minValue                    : 0,
        maxValue                    : 650,
        
        minAngle                    : -90,
        maxAngle                    : 90,
        
        transitionMs                : 750,
        
        majorTicks                  : 600,
        
        labelFormat                 : d3.format(',g'),
        labelInset                  : 100,
        
        arcColorFn                  : d3.interpolateHsl(d3.rgb('#f64e60'), d3.rgb('#41a4fe'))
    };
    var range = undefined;
    var r = undefined;
    var pointerHeadLength = undefined;
    var value = 0;
    
    var svg = undefined;
    var arc = undefined;
    var scale = undefined;
    var ticks = undefined;
    var tickData = undefined;
    var pointer = undefined;
    var valueText = undefined;

    var donut = d3.layout.pie();
    
    function deg2rad(deg) {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }
    
    function newAngle(d) {
        var ratio = scale(d);
        var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
        return newAngle;
    }
    
    function configure(configuration) {
        var prop = undefined;
        for ( prop in configuration ) {
            config[prop] = configuration[prop];
        }
        
        range = config.maxAngle - config.minAngle;
        r = config.size / 2;
        pointerHeadLength = Math.round(r * config.pointerHeadLengthPercent);

        // a linear scale that maps domain values to a percent from 0..1
        scale = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([0,1])
            .domain([config.minValue, config.maxValue]);
            
        ticks = scale.ticks(config.majorTicks);
        tickData = d3.range(config.majorTicks).map(function() {return 1/config.majorTicks;});
        
        arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(r - config.ringWidth - config.ringInset)
            .outerRadius(r - config.ringInset)
            .startAngle(function(d, i) {
                var ratio = d * i;
                return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
            })
            .endAngle(function(d, i) {
                var ratio = d * (i+1);
                return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
            });
    }
    that.configure = configure;
    
    function centerTranslation() {
        return 'translate('+r +','+ r +')';
    }
    
    function isRendered() {
        return (svg !== undefined);
    }
    that.isRendered = isRendered;
    
    function render(newValue) {
        svg = d3.select(container)
            .append('svg:svg')
                .attr('class', 'gauge')
                .attr('width', config.clipWidth)
                .attr('height', config.clipHeight);
        
        var centerTx = centerTranslation();
        
        var arcs = svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'arc')
                .attr('transform', centerTx); 
                
                
        arcs.selectAll('path')
                .data(tickData)
            .enter().append('path')
                .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                    return config.arcColorFn(d * i);
                })
                .attr('d', arc);
        
        var lg = svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'label')
                .attr('transform', centerTx);
        lg.selectAll('text')
                .data(ticks)
            //.enter().append('text')
                .attr('transform', function(d) {
                    var ratio = scale(d);
                    var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio *                                                          range);
                    return 'rotate(' +newAngle +') translate(0,' +(config.labelInset - r) +')';
                })
                .text(config.labelFormat);

        var lineData = [ [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0], 
                        [0, -pointerHeadLength],
                        [-(config.pointerWidth / 2), 0],
                        [0, config.pointerTailLength],
                        [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0] ];
        var pointerLine = d3.svg.line().interpolate('monotone');
        var pg = svg.append('g').data([lineData])
                .attr('class', 'pointer')
                .attr('transform', centerTx);
                
        pointer = pg.append('path')
            .attr('d', pointerLine)
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +config.minAngle + ')');

        valueText = pg.append('text').attr('text-anchor', 'middle');
        update(newValue = 430);
        
        //== undefined ? 0 : newValue);
    }
    that.render = render;
    
    function update(newValue, newConfiguration) {
        if ( newConfiguration  !== undefined) {
            configure(newConfiguration);
        }
        var ratio = scale(newValue);
        var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
        pointer.transition()
            .duration(config.transitionMs)
            .ease('elastic')
            .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +newAngle +')');
       
       console.log(newValue, ':', newAngle);
       let a = newAngle / 180 * Math.PI;
       if (a < 0) a += Math.PI * 2;
       const x = 195 * Math.sin(a);
       const y = 195 * -Math.cos(a);
       valueText.text(newValue).attr('x', x).attr('y', y);
    }
    that.update = update;

    configure(configuration);
    
    return that;
};
</script>

<script>
function onDocumentReady() {
    var powerGauge = gauge('#action', {
        size: 400,
        clipWidth: 400,
        clipHeight: 400,
        ringWidth: 80,
        maxValue: 650,
        transitionMs: 4000,
    });
    powerGauge.render();
    powerGauge.update(110);


    
    var powerGauge2 = gauge('#action1', {
        size: 400,
        clipWidth: 400,
        clipHeight: 400,
        ringWidth: 80,
        maxValue: 650,
        transitionMs: 4000,
    });
    powerGauge2.render();
    powerGauge2.update(500);
    

//window.setTimeout(function() {
//  custom.update(120);
//}, 4000);



window.setTimeout(function() {
  custom2.update(68);
}, 4000);
    
    
    // every few seconds update reading values
    //updateReadings();
    //setInterval(function() {
        //updateReadings();
    //}, 1000);
}

if ( !window.isLoaded ) {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        onDocumentReady();
    }, false);
} else {
    onDocumentReady();
}
```

```css
    body {
        font-family:  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 32px;
    }

    #power-gauge g.arc {
        fill: red;
    }

    #power-gauge g.pointer {
        fill: yellow;
        stroke: yellow;
    }
    
    #power-gauge g.label text {
        text-anchor: middle;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        fill: #000;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <title>Gauge</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="action"></div>
<div id="action1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```